# Sneg Library - Number operator simplify

Tags: packages, physics

I am trying to use the SNEG Library for evaluating some commutators. For instance I am trying to evaluate 
$$ \left[n_1^2,a^\dagger_1\right]$$
with the code in Mathematica

```
<< sneg`;
snegbosonoperators[a];
nSquare = (nc[number[a[1]], number[a[1]]]);
aCR1 = a[CR, 1];
Comm1 = komutator[nSquare, aCR1] // SnegFullSimplify
```

The result using SNEG is 
$$ a_1^\dagger + 2 a_1^\dagger \cdot a_1^\dagger \cdot a_1  $$.

However I would like to simplify it to 
$$ a_1^\dagger + 2 a_1^\dagger \cdot n_1  $$, automatically.

Is there any way to tell SNEG to simplify the expression in this way?

Comment: You could write your own replacement rule, ```snegbosonoperators[n]; Comm1 /. 
 nc[bef___, sym_[0, 1], sym_[1, 1], aft___] :> nc[bef, n[1, 1], aft]```

Comment: Thank you! It's a good idea and it works.

Comment: Anyhow how this could be generalized to the case of more operators, namely $n_1$, $n_2$, ... ?

Comment: Sneg is a very nice QFT package. I had seen it many years ago and then forgotten it. I am glad you brought it up. Unfortunately it seems that it has not been maintained that much in the recent years. For example the documentation files, which seem quite good (see the "number" doc file for example ), are not directly accessible from the documentation center in version 11.3 . I have not tested older versions. Which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: I now try to contact the developer and see what we can do about it

Comment: I am using Mathematica 11.3 and sneg seems to work without any problem. Anyhow documentation is not accessible from the documentation centre as you pointed out

Comment: @Galuoises what do you want to do with sneg? It seems the package is good for some non commutative algebra used in qft and has many functions dealing with solid state physics (which I do not know). But if you want to calculate amplitudes, then perhaps you should consider Feyncalc.

Comment: I find it useful to evaluate commutators or to check them, so I would like to use all its power to simplify as much as possible the expressions